# IPSEC VPN Router / Firewall

Tags: vpn, firewall, router, ipsec

I'm not sure whether it's the right place to ask for a router / firewall recommendation.

My requirements are as follows:

- supports IPSEC tunnels (at least two connections)
- has WAN/LAN throughput of almost 100Mbit/s and in VPN mode at least 50Mbit/s
- shouldn't be noisy, because is for home office
- the price range is up to $500

I've some Cisco 2600/3600 and PIX 515E available, but these are to noisy and the power consumption is quite too much. But they would fulfil my requirements ;)

Comment: You'll never get 50MBit through a 2600 router.

Comment: okey, i've never tested the throughput on a cisco 2600.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q and A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You want quite a high throughput, but for not very much money.
That's going to be tricky.
The only sensible device I can think of which ticks all of your boxes is the Cisco ASA 5505.  100Mbit WAN/LAN, 150Mbit VPN Throughput.  Small form factor, fanless (I think),
and Quite Cheap (Local pricing may vary, but they're less than 300 GBP)

Comment: ASA5505 would also be my choice, wonderful little boxes.